# SQL Job running a few select statements Incorrect syntax near '\'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)

Tags: sql, syntax-error, sql-job

I have a SQL job that contains a few select statements (4 views and 1 text).

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Database Email',
    @recipients = 'dbcheck@xxx.com',
    @subject = 'SQL Replication Deletion Check',
    @query = 'SELECT '\\server1\folder1\SQL\check.sql' AS [Script]
SELECT * FROM [repserv].[dbo].[1repdupecheck]
SELECT * FROM [repserv].[dbo].[2repdupecheck]
SELECT * FROM [repserv].[dbo].[3repdupecheck]
SELECT * FROM [repserv].[dbo].[4repdupecheck]',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1;
```

I currently get the following error when running it.

```
Message
Executed as user: SERVER1\sqlusr. Incorrect syntax near '\'. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102).  The step failed.
```

Now I have also tried taking out the line with the `'\'` in and it works so I can only assume a bracket or something needs to be put around the back slashes in the select text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes and quotes

```
'SELECT ''\\\\server1\\folder1\\SQL\\check.sql'' AS [Script]
```

Comment: Thanks man! Pretty much got it, didn't need the double back slashes though just escape the single quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Got it with help from the below, just needed to add double single quotes (didn't need to double up on back slashes)

```
'SELECT ''\\server1\folder1\SQL\check.sql'' AS [Script]
```